# Any idea what is causing this SQL/ASP.NET Login error?

Tags: asp.net, sql, authentication

Symptoms:

If I wait 15-20 minutes, then try to login to my web site, I get the following stack trace / error.  If I hit refresh after about 20 seconds, everything works fine.  I would REALLY like to make the site stop doing this.

*edit*  Am I the only one that thinks he or she figures out the problem right after asking the question?  I have an ASP SQLDataSource that is on the Master Page.  I just added this to the Selecting event:

```
If Not System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
    e.Cancel = True
End If
```

I'll post back the results in about half an hour or so - DID NOT FIX THE PROBLEM

*/edit*

*edit_2*
Here's the SQL DataSource

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQLds_ClientSearch" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:meta_db_ConStr %>" SelectCommand="Select * from View_Clients WHERE (ClientName LIKE @Search + '%' OR SISAR LIKE @Search + '%') ">
       <SelectParameters>
           <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Search_tb" Name="Search"
           PropertyName="Text" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="False" />
       </SelectParameters>
   </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And here's the connection under my web.config

```
<connectionStrings>    
<add name="meta_db_ConStr" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\meta_db.mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

*/edit_2*

Stack trace:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +5064458
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +234
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.WriteSni() +5073467
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.WritePacket(Byte flushMode) +254
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsLogin(SqlLogin rec) +1832
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.Login(ServerInfo server, TimeoutTimer timeout, String newPassword) +320
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject) +161
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout) +239
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +195
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +232
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +185
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +33
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +524
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +66
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +479
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +108
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +126
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +125
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +123
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +319
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable) +92
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +1618
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +21
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +143
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +4
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +66
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls() +75
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +102
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2496
```

Comment: Are you using a Session variable to store your connection string, or credential information for the database?  Perhaps you can show the definition of your SQLDataSource

Comment: I just edited the original question with the connectionStrings and SQLDataSource

Comment: Perhaps the solution is here? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175496(v=sql.105).aspx